# Parse bpftrace output data

Tags: ruby

I'm looking at trying to parse the below output from a bpftrace file, using ruby. I thought about splitting on the `'|'` and then I need to get the values from `"[4, 8) 824"` for example. Need to get these two values into an array. I was thinking about using the trim method as well, but surely there must be a better way - maybe using a regular expression. Can I please get some guidance on how to proceed, please?

Input: `[4, 8) 824 |@@@@ |`

```
first_array = []
text=File.foreach('/.../test.txt').with_index do |line|
   puts "#{line}"
   values=line.split("|")

   first_array=values[0].split(" ")
   puts first_array
```

Comment: Do not change the content of the question with what was proposed in answers. The question must stay as it was stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to split by `'|'`, split by non-digit out of the box:

```
input = '[4, 8) 824 |@@@@ |'
input.split(/\D+/).reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
#⇒ [4, 8, 824]
```

or, as suggested by Cary in comments:

```
input.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
#⇒ [4, 8, 824]
```

Comment: Perhaps `scan` would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. However, when i put it in the code above, it outputs each value on new line.  Not sure what i am missing? Trying to read in from a file which has lots of rows of similar input values.

Comment: @apaterson `Kernel#puts` prints arrays that way, each element on its own line. Use `puts arr.inspect` instead to see all of them on the same line, or like.-

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Still learning ruby at the moment, so thanks for providing your help/information. Fully understand now.